# SWIFT - table.reloadData() not / stopped working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to refresh a tableView using table.reloadData() in SWIFT 3.
I managed to get this working some time ago but now it simply stopped working out of the blue. No errors, no warning, nothing.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    print("MainVC > viewWillAppear")

    super.viewWillAppear(animated) 
    initializeCollectionView()
}

func initializeCollectionView()
{
    print("MainVC > initializeCollectionView")

    projectsArray = []
    getDocumentDirectoryContent()

    if(projectsArray.count > 0)
    {
        print(projectsArray.count)

        //For testing only - To make sure the array is not empty
        for var i in 0..<projectsArray.count
        {
            print(projectsArray[i].project_name)
        }

        cvProjects.isHidden = false
        ivMainVCPlaceholder.isHidden = true
    }
    else
    {
        cvProjects.isHidden = true
        ivMainVCPlaceholder.isHidden = false

        cvProjects.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Every time the app starts it calls the it grabs the data from `documentDirectory` and fills in the `projectsArray` array with objects. This works just fine.

The `initializeCollectionView` is called in `viewWillAppear` because the `tableView` was also supposed to be refreshed when a child `viewController` is dismissed. It is also called on tap:

```
@IBAction func btnRefreshCollectionAction(_ sender: Any)
{
    print("MainVC > btnRefreshCollectionAction")

    initializeCollectionView()
}
```

The problem is now the table won't refresh neither when a child `viewController` is dismissed nor when I tap on `btnRefreshCollectionAction`.

However, the `projectsArray` array is not empty in `initializeCollectionView`.

My first thought was to blame the Xcode upgrade I performed right before I noticed this stopped working but usually if there is any problem after an upgrade there are warnings and/or errors.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well you're only calling `reloadData` when `projectsArray.count` is 0.

Comment: So this might be a crude observation, but shouldn't you also be reloading the data if the count of the objects you fetched > 0? Because as I can see from the code you supplied, if the array is not empty, you don't reload!

Comment: Now I feel dumb :| And I've been staring at it for some time. Thanks guys :D

Comment: A good indication would have to check `numberOfSections(in tableView:)` and/or `tableView(_ tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:)` ;)

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are calling reload method only when the array is empty. When you have objects in an array you are executing some other code but not reload. Either write reload method in `viewWillAppear` or else put reload method in `If` condition also. That should work.